# How to find a code that triggers the pop up window (lightbox)?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

So I'm trying to remove a lightbox pop-up window that is triggered once per session and once the website is loaded. How can I find that line of code that is triggering it if there are 100+ files and easily one of the most unorganized website structure I've ever seen.

The lightbox that is being used is called EasyBox.

Any ideas where to look for the trigger function? I couldn't find anything with "onLoad".

Comment: In my HTML document that uses a lightbox it works like this: `<a href="images/pt1.gif" rel="lightbox[pt]" title="Adding home / away talk entries">`. Does a search for **box** yield any potential candidates?

Comment: I've seen the code that open the box once I click a link (which is fine) but I am looking for the line that opens the lightbox automatically (once the page is loaded) without any action of the user..

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: So 110+ files and we need to guess where the line of code might be without even a link to the site? That's like saying my car won't start, why?